# What's the translation of "healthspan" in French?

Tags: traduction

Healthspan [is](https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=fr&text=healthspan%20&op=translate):

> the part of a person’s life during which they are generally in good health.

What's the translation of "healthspan" in French?

[Google translate](https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=fr&text=healthspan%20&op=translate) and [Lingue](https://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?source=auto&query=healthspan) didn't help.

Comment: I entered [a sentence found on the internet](https://publichealth.wustl.edu/heatlhspan-is-more-important-than-lifespan-so-why-dont-more-people-know-about-it/) [in DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator#en/fr/Healthspan%20is%20more%20important%20than%20lifespan%2C%20so%20why%20don%E2%80%99t%20more%20people%20know%20about%20it%3F) and it gave me what I think is a perfectly good translation.  Of course the result given by google translate is very different, not to say stupid. Giving the word a context when using a translator helps as well.

Comment: @None thanks, good point!

Comment: *The Deepl translation is a translation error*. espérance de vie is life expectancy. health=bonne santé, span: durée. healthspan: durée de vie en bonne santé.

Comment: @Lambie Deepl translation is *espérance de vie en bonne santé* and not *espérance de vie*, *espérance de vie en bonne santé* & *espérance de vie* are different concepts.

Comment: @None Ce commentaire me laisse coite. *espérance de vie* et *durée de vie* sont différents; life expectancy and lifespan.

Comment: Thankfully you provided the translation of "healthspan" into English!

Comment: the part of a person’s life during which they are generally in good health.  Nothing to do with life expectancy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si l'on s'en tient à la définition de *healthspan* trouvée dans les dictionnaires, et de la même façon que l'anglais met en relation *lifespan* et *healthspan*, le français met en relation **l'espérance de vie** et **l'espérance de vie en bonne santé**.

Définition qui se trouve [sur le site de l'INSEE](https://www.insee.fr/fr/metadonnees/definition/c2017):

> L'espérance de vie en bonne santé est la durée de vie moyenne en bonne santé - c'est-à-dire sans limitation irréversible d'activité dans la vie quotidienne ni incapacités - d'une génération fictive soumise aux conditions de mortalité et de morbidité de l'année. Elle caractérise la mortalité et la morbidité indépendamment de la structure par âge.
> Espérance de vie en bonne santé (soit AVBS pour **a**nnées de **v**ie en **b**onne **s**anté)
> Espérance de vie sans incapacité (EVSI)

> Au niveau global, l'espérance de vie a augmenté avec le progrès de la médecine et l'amélioration de la qualité de vie. [...] Il existe d'ailleurs une variante de cet indicateur, appelée espérance de vie en bonne santé, qui évalue le nombre moyen d'années qu'un individu peut vivre sans incapacité. ([Futura Sciences](https://www.futura-sciences.com/sante/definitions/medecine-esperance-vie-5127/))

> L’espérance de vie en bonne santé donne une indication du nombre d’années qu’une personne d’un certain âge peut espérer vivre en bonne santé. ([Éducation santé.be](https://educationsante.be/lesperance-de-vie-en-bonne-sante-des-belges/))

> Qu’en est-il de ce que l’on appelle l’espérance de vie en bonne santé, à savoir le nombre d’années que l’on peut espérer vivre sans souffrir d’incapacité dans les gestes de la vie quotidienne ?  ([Une association d'assurés](https://www.anpere.fr/vivre-en-bonne-sante-jusqua-quel-age/))

L'expression est très utilisée en France depuis que la réforme des retraites est sur la sellette, [les exemples sont très nombreux](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22esp%C3%A9rance%20de%20vie%20en%20bonne%20sant%C3%A9%22&lr=&safe=images&as_qdr=all&ei=eEDhYYzxFM24aZy1iJgH&start=40&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwiMjfGP9bD1AhVNXBoKHZwaAnM4HhDy0wN6BAgBEEY&biw=1860&bih=909&dpr=1).

> L'espérance de vie en bonne santé ne progresse plus depuis dix ans en France ([Le quotidien du médecin](https://www.lequotidiendumedecin.fr/actus-medicales/sante-publique/lesperance-de-vie-en-bonne-sante-ne-progresse-plus-depuis-dix-ans-en-france))

> Après 65 ans, une espérance de vie en bonne santé en hausse. ([Service public.fr](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/actualites/A15284))

Here is the original sentence from [an article](https://cordis.europa.eu/article/id/31993-eat-less-for-a-longer-healthier-life-new-research-suggests) published on the CORDIS<sup>1</sup> website:

> We want to use the discoveries about calorie restriction and other related genetic or pharmacological interventions to close that 30-year gap **between life span and 'health span'**<sup>2</sup>.

and its translation in [French](https://cordis.europa.eu/article/id/31993-eat-less-for-a-longer-healthier-life-new-research-suggests/fr) (the translations for CORDIS are made by certified language services):

> Nous souhaitons utiliser ces découvertes sur la restriction calorique et d'autres interventions génétiques ou pharmacologiques connexes pour combler ce fossé de 30 ans **entre l'espérance de vie et 'l'espérance de vie en bonne santé'**<sup>2</sup>.

Dans les publications québécoises on trouve l'expression *espérance de santé* mais je ne l'ai jamais rencontrée en France.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> [CORDIS](https://cordis.europa.eu/en) is the *Community Research and Development Information Service* for the European Union.

<sup>2</sup> My emphasis.</sup>

Comment: espérance de vie, c'est life expectancy.

Comment: @Lambie  « espérance de vie » et « espérance de vie en bonne santé » sont ne sont pas les mêmes concepts.  Il n'y a pas de différence entre la définition   de *healthspan* donnée par le PO et celle qu'on peut trouver en français, e.g.   « L'espérance de vie en bonne santé est la durée de vie moyenne en bonne santé » (site de l'Insee).

Comment: Mais non: espérance de vie en bonne santé is: life expectancy in good health. espérance de vie, tout seul: life expectancy. Par contre: durée de vie en bonne santé serait: healthspan. span=durée. There is just no doubt here. Sorry.

Comment: Termium, that great French Canadian resource confirms this: https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=esp%C3%A9rance+de+vie&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs

Comment: https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=lifespan&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs pour lifespan, durée de vie

Comment: That Cordis article in French and in English uses life span and durée de vie. If you check the French for this: https://cordis.europa.eu/article/id/31993-eat-less-for-a-longer-healthier-life-new-research-suggests Eat less for a longer healthier life, the French version says: durée de vie for the English term lifespan.

Answer (score 1):

Neither English, nor French native. Here are my two cents taking into account the definition [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/dictionnaire/anglais/lifespan).

> These drugs can improve healthspan and lifespan in mice.

may be conveyed by

> Ces médicaments peuvent améliorer la durée de vie en bonne santé et la durée de vie des souris.

To avoid repetition one might say

> Ces médicaments peuvent améliorer la durée de vie en bonne santé et l'espérance de vie des souris.

For human beings I propose also **bien veillir**. This implies staying in good health for a long time and is often used in marketing to advertise healthy food.

Comment: How, pray tell, is this different from what I said?

Comment: @Lambie You have given your answer. I don't understand why somebody other cannot answer even if their answer is along the same lines. There is no plagiarism here:-)!

Comment: Oh, I just realized that you think durée de vie and durée de vie en bonne santé can be durée de vie and espérance de vie to avoid repetition. It blows my mind that no one seems to get that espérance is expectancy and durée is span.  No one seems to realize that the scientific terms: lifespan and life expectancy are two separate terms. And that healthspan is formed with span, not expectancy.

Answer (score 0):

Voici un article de France Culture:
1.

> L’augmentation de l’espérance de vie est souvent considérée comme le
> marqueur essentiel des résultats positifs du progrès dans la société.
> C’est l’argument majeur que l’on oppose à ceux qui critiquent la
> civilisation occidentale. Or, voici qu’une notion assez nouvelle remet
> en cause l’évolution indéniablement positive des pays développés dans
> ce domaine. Il s’agit de la notion de « **durée de vie en bonne
> santé** ». Pas facile à définir, certes. Mais les critères deviennent
> de plus en plus précis et efficaces avec l’indicateur baptisé «
> Espérance de vie sans incapacité » (EVSI). Elle désigne une vie sans
> limitations des fonctions essentielles telles que les aptitudes à se
> déplacer, se nourrir, se vêtir. Une absence de dépendance majeure en
> somme. Or, l’utilisation de cet instrument donne des résultats
> surprenants.

[espérance de vie](https://www.franceculture.fr/emissions/science-publique/pourquoi-lesperance-de-vie-en-bonne-sante-diminue-t-elle)

- **espérance de vie** en anglais, c'est: life expectancy
- **healthspan** veut dire: **durée de vie en bonne santé**
- **lifespan**: **durée de vie**
- span: durée

2. 

> L’allongement de **la durée de vie en bonne santé** : mythe ou réalité
> ? [Penser santé](https://www.pensersante.fr/vit-plus-longtemps-en-bonne-sante)

3. 

> **La durée de vie en bonne santé mesure par conséquent le nombre
> d'années qu'une personne d'un âge donné s'attend à vivre sans problème
> de santé grave ou modéré**, en continuant ses activités habituelles. A
> la différence de l'espérance de vie tout court - qui repose sur des
> données démographiques objectives -, l'espérance de vie en bonne santé
> s'appuie en effet sur une approche déclarative, obtenue par sondage
> auprès d'un échantillon d'Européens.
>
> [la durée de vie en bonne santé](https://www.banquedesterritoires.fr/esperance-de-vie-en-bonne-sante-des-ecarts-importants-en-europe)

Il suffit de régarder TERMIUM. pour:

lifespan = durée de vie
et
life expectancy = espérance de vie

> [Life expectancy](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=LIFE%20EXPECTANCY&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs)
>
> [lifespan](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=lifespan&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs)

4. 

**Grand Dictionnaire Terminologique:**

**lifespan** EN • **durée de la vie** FR
**démographie | biologie**

Espace de temps qui s'écoule entre la naissance et le décès d'un individu.
Logo identifiant une fiche rédigée par l’Office québécois de la langue française Office québécois de la langue française, 1999

life span EN • durée de vie FR
électricité

Hydro-Québec, 1971

Comment: Note à la personne qui a donné un vote négatif à cette réponse: Vous vous trompez.

Comment: En plus d'être médiocre typographiquement parlant, cette réponse promeut l'expression la moins idiomatique et cherche à démontrer que deux concepts de sens identique en français s'opposent alors même que l'article cité démontre l'inverse.

Comment: La réponse ne promeut rien du tout. La réponse montre la différence entre lifespan, healthspan et life expectancy. Là je trouve que tu dépasses le bon sens, sans parler du fait de sombrer dans la mauvaise foi. C'est vraiment dommage.

Comment: La réponse ne montre pas la différence entre *lifespan*, *healthspan* et *life expectancy* puisqu'aucune référence en anglais n'y figure ni aucune explication de cette différence. La réponse affirme que les deux expressions ne signifient pas la même chose mais l'article cité semble affiner la définition de "durée de vie en bonne santé" (que tu as graissé sans le signaler) en proposant "espérance de vie sans incapacité* qui lui n'a pas été graissé. L'auteur de l'article identifie donc les deux expressions. Après réflexion, tu as raison, il y a bien une nuance, mais tu ne l'as pas démontré.

Comment: Affirmer n'est pas démontrer et le *lifespan* de TERMIUM Plus n'a pas grand chose à voir avec le sujet (pollution, couche d'ozone). Donne plutôt un exemple convaincant de phrase existante en anglais contenant *healthspan* où ce mot ne peut pas se traduire par "espérance de vie en bonne santé" mais peut l'être par "durée de vie en bonne santé".

Comment: Ta troisième citation ne fait pas non plus de différence entre "durée de vie en bonne santé", qui n'apparaît qu'une seule fois dans la source, et "espérance de vie en bonne santé", qui apparaît huit fois dans la source. Ce sont donc des synonymes pour l'auteur.

Answer (score -1):

There has not been time enough for a rendering in French to be devised for "healthspan" because it is a term that has been in use for only five years ([Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/healthspan)).

Using the definition of the [Cambridge Dictionary's](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/healthspan) (
the number of years that someone lives or can expect to live in reasonably good health) a periphrastic term could be conceived as follows.

- durée de vie hors morbidité

Comment: Five years??? Oldest example given by [macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/buzzword/entries/healthspan.html): 2002. [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/what-is-health-span): 1987. I found one from 1885. But I admit that's *hors de propos* on FL. Can you give a few uses of *durée de vie hors morbidité*, in context, I haven't found any. I'm not sure I understand you use of the word *morbidité here (well let's say I disagree with it...)

Comment: @None That is what the comments in Macmillan say: The term healthspan has featured in medical research for the last five years, though is yet to be formally recorded in a published dictionary. // No, I can't give any instances of use, since I made it up; any way, it is more or less self explanatory: a definition is hardly needed.// simply "État de maladie, déséquilibre psychique ou mental plus ou moins profond" ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/morbidit%C3%A9))

Comment: you wrote "[the] term has been in use for only five years" which is a very loose interpretation of "The term healthspan has featured in medical research for the last five years"!

Comment: @None By  "in use" I think one can understand "in use with a reasonable degree of currency"; this is corroborated by the fact (same reference) that it was not (at least until recently) recorded in a published dictionary.